# Registered a GoDaddy domain through Blogger

Tags: blogger, domain

I just registered the domain www.yannbane.com for my Blogger blog (which is at http://yannbane.blogspot.com/).

I used this tool to do it:

[image]

Well, this lead me to a Google page where I needed to enter some info, and for $10, I got the domain. Yay. But, there is a problem. First off, http://www.yannbane.com has a 404 error. I expected Google and GoDaddy to configure the website, but it seems like they didn't. When I add my domain with "advanced settings" shown in that picture, still, nothing happens.

What am I supposed to do? I don't have a GoDaddy account, for that matter. Also, I got two emails from Google, one telling me that the transaction was successful, and the other telling me how I registered a domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue.

I needed to log into Domain Control Center and unlock my domain. Instructions can be found here: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71281.